# check if value exists in json array

Tags: json, jquery

I want to check via js/jquery if a value exits in a json array:

```
[{"pathway_action_fk":"1"},{"pathway_action_fk":"2"},{"pathway_action_fk":"4"}]
```

I have tried without success:

```
 $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "scripts/get_actions_allowed.php",
       data: 'pathway=' + pathway_pk,
      dataType: "json",
       success: function(returnedData) {
if ($.inArray('1', returnedData)){
    $('#script').addClass('active');
}...
```

If I put in after success:

```
alert(returnedData);
```

I get`[object Object],[object Object]` which is the correct number of objects that should be returned.  Removing json as dataType shows the correct values...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your array contains JSON objects.  So you need to look inside of each object to see if its field has the desired value (or at least, that's what I gather you're trying to do judging by your code).

So perhaps something along the lines of:

```
$(returnedData).each(function() {
    if (this.pathway_action_fk == 1) {
        $('#script').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/qvsbT/

Answer (score 1):

The elements of the array are objects, not strings. The values you want to check are the `pathway_action_fk` properties of those objects. So you have to drill down before checking.

```
if ($.inArray('1', returnedData.map(function(x) {
    return x.pathway_action_fk;
})) != -1);
```

Also, you need to compare the result of `$.inArray` with `-1` -- it returns the found element's index, which can be 0, not a boolean.

Comment: Thanks for this...tried the code but couldn't get it working, though that is probably my failure to implement it properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "scripts/get_actions_allowed.php",
    data: 'pathway=' + pathway_pk,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(returnedData)
    {
        for(var i=0, max=returnedData.length; i<max; i++)
        {
            if(returnedData[i].pathwy_action_fk==='1')
            {
                $('#script').addClass('active');
                break;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: This is just like the original code, you're not looking in the `pathway_action_fk` property.

Comment: Ouch, yeah, sorry. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var JSN = 
[
    {
        "email": "msshah@gmail.com"
    }, 
    {
        "email": "ms@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "email": "ams@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "email": "no@gmail.com"
    }
];
// var hasMatch =false;
$(JSN).each(function() {
    if (this.email == "yes@gmail.com") {
        alert("found:  " + JSON.stringify(this));
    }else{
        alert('Not Found');

    }

});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/wfh9ur1j/5/